# Multiple select list com itens já selecionados utilizando Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, multiple

Estou utilizando `Razor` para gerar uma `SelectList` assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusImovel", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaStatus, "IdStatus", "Descricao"), new { @hidden = "hidden", @multiple = "multiple", @form = "nulo" })
```

Preciso que ela carregue já com alguns itens selecionados, então estou tentando isto:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusImovel", new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaStatus, "IdStatus", "Descricao", ViewBag.StatusSelecionados), new { @hidden = "hidden", @multiple = "multiple", @form = "nulo" })
```

Sendo que `ViewBag.StatusSelecionados` é um `array int[]` com os `IdStatus` que quero.
mas não está funcionando.

Tem algum modo de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando o helper errado, se você quer que vários valores sejam selecionados, você precisa utilizar o `MultiSelectList()`

```
@Html.DropDownList("StatusImovel", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.ListaStatus, "IdStatus", "Descricao", ViewBag.StatusSelecionados), new { @hidden = "hidden", @multiple = "multiple", @form = "nulo" })
```

Comment: Boa Leandro! Funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: @AlamO Então marca como a resposta :)